# Symfony2 - Country-Region-City. Ajax-collection

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony2

День добрый.
Въезжаю в Symfony и тут же понадобилось реализовать следующее.

**Есть БД стран, областей и регионов. Имеет это все следующую архитектуру**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * .....
 */    
Abstract class AbstractGeoItem {

    public function getName();

    public function getParent();
}

class City extends AbstractGeoItem {}
class Region extends AbstractGeoItem {}
class Country extends AbstractGeoItem {}
```

Есть entity Traveler, в которой есть переменная **places** которая является ArrayCollection контейнером для AbstractGeoItem.

```
class Traveler {
/**
     * @var
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="GeoBundle\Entity\AbstractGeoPlace", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $places;
}
```

Задача такова, что мне нужно прикрутить ajax форму с возможностью добавления/удаления в коллекцию places новых мест AbstractGeoPlace.

Подскажите, может быть есть уже какие-либо готовые бандлы для реализации подобной задачи ? Если нет, подскажите, какими бы Вы инструментами руководствовались при реализации ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можете взглянуть на GenemuFormBundle https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/select2/ajax.md

Если не все вам подойдет, то на решение, думаю, натолкнет.